# I want to calculate all the totals using JQUERY by adding the CR and Subtracting DR Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a form that contains three fields. The second field consists of a  debit or credit option which means the total should be calculated by that option.

If I select debit the total should be subtracted by the current value

I tried but I was getting only the totals without debit or credit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".txt").each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
    });
  });
});

function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  style="width:40%"
}

th,
td {
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: 1px solid green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:60%">
  <caption>Tally Ledgers</caption>
  <tr>
    <th width="60">Head</th>
    <th width="5">DR/CR</th>
    <th width="15">Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="tally" type="tally" id="tally" name="tally" placeholder="tally"></td>
    <td>
      <select id="cr_dr" name="cr_dr">
        <option value="">Select Credit Or Debit</option>
        <option value="+">CR</option>
        <option value="-">DR</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td width="15"><input class="txt" type="text" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Amount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="tally1" type="tally1" id="tally1" name="tally1" placeholder="tally1"></td>
    <td>
      <select id="cr_dr1" name="cr_dr1">
        <option value="">Select Credit Or Debit</option>
        <option value="+">CR</option>
        <option value="-">DR</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td width="15"><input class="txt" type="text" id="amount1" name="amount1" placeholder="Amount1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="summation">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Total :</td>
    <td align="center"><output type="text" id="sum" name="sum" value="sum">0</output></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: please find image]

Comment: Can you add a small sample of the HTML to the question.

Comment: You are just adding up the numbers, you dont look at the DR or CR to decide if you need to + or - this value

Comment: Please click edit, then the `[<>]` snippet editor button and provide relevant HTML and script in a [mcve] - there is no Ajax, PHP or mySQL here

Comment: Added HTML code Please Help

Comment: sir now i updated HTML please see once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the name beginning with cr_dr since they do not have a class

I changed output to an input field and change .text to .val for it based on your wish to submit it

```
<input type="text" id="sum" name="sum" value="0" />

$("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2))
```

---

```js
const calculateSum = function() {
  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function() {
    let val = isNaN(this.value) || this.value.trim().length === 0 ? 0 : +this.value; // cast to number
    const drcr = $(this).closest("tr").find("[name^=cr_dr]").val(); // name begins with cr_dr
    sum += val * (drcr === "-" ? -1 : 1); // ternary based on the value
    $(this).toggleClass("neg",drcr === "-"); // remove if you do not want this
  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum")
  .val(sum.toFixed(2))
  .toggleClass("neg",sum<0); // remove if you do not want this
  
}

$(function() {
  $(".txt").on("input", calculateSum);
  $("select").on("change", calculateSum);
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  style="width:40%"
}

th,
td {
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: 1px solid green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
}
.neg { color:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:60%">
  <caption>Tally Ledgers</caption>
  <tr>
    <th width="60">Head</th>
    <th width="5">DR/CR</th>
    <th width="15">Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="tally" type="tally" id="tally" name="tally" placeholder="tally"></td>
    <td>
      <select id="cr_dr" name="cr_dr">
        <option value="">Select Credit Or Debit</option>
        <option value="+">CR</option>
        <option value="-">DR</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td width="15"><input class="txt" type="text" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Amount"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="tally1" type="tally1" id="tally1" name="tally1" placeholder="tally1"></td>
    <td>
      <select id="cr_dr1" name="cr_dr1">
        <option value="">Select Credit Or Debit</option>
        <option value="+">CR</option>
        <option value="-">DR</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td width="15"><input class="txt" type="text" id="amount1" name="amount1" placeholder="Amount1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="summation">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Total :</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" id="sum" name="sum" value="0" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry sir somebody closed this question I was new to stackoverflow I added HTML code in snippet please help

Comment: what i want is i will select one option either CR or DR if i select CR the value should be consider as positive if i select DR the value should be considered as positive the the total should be displayed in the total cell

Comment: You mean, CR postitive DR ***negative*** - I updated the code. See how fast I was once I saw the actual HTML!!!

Comment: PS: You really should wrap the table sections in `thead` and `tbody`

Comment: PPS: I updated to add a red color. Remove if you do not need

Comment: thank you so much sir . it was working perfectly thanks a lot
sir small help how to insert output field of this script to mysql  please help[

Comment: no sir i am asking how to insert
<output type="text" id="sum" name="sum" value="sum">0</output>
this field to database i am able to insert entire form but unable to insert this HTML field

Comment: if i keep it as input which is read only it's not loading any answer sir

Comment: Change `<output type="text" id="sum" name="sum" value="sum">0</output>` to `<input type="text" id="sum" name="sum" value="0" readonly />` - then you can submit it.

Comment: i did it but the result remains 0 only if i change values of the amount also

Comment: Thank you so much! sir you made my day
thanks a lot sir

Comment: sir please check this once
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884064/how-to-display-a-child-table-under-the-main-table-without-repeating-main-data-ea